# website not working server Error in / Application

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, configuration, web-config

Server Error in '/' Application.

This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator

> **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details**: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator
>
> **Source Error**: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace**: 
>   [Win32Exception (0x80004005): This program is blocked by group policy. For more     information, contact your system administrator]
>      [ExternalException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was     "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths    @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET     Files\root\d7e8c5c7\64d2ef8e\12ln453k.cmdline".]
>        System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCaptureUnimpersonated(SafeUserTokenHandle     userToken, String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection tempFiles, String& outputName,     String& errorName, String trueCmdLine) +6537691
>          System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture(SafeUserTokenHandle userToken,    String cmd, String currentDir, TempFileCollection tempFiles, String& outputName, String&    errorName, String trueCmdLine) +115
>          Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.Compile(CompilerParameters options, String     compilerDirectory, String compilerExe, String arguments, String& outputFile, Int32&     nativeReturnValue, String trueArgs) +263
>          Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[]     fileNames) +473
>          Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyF    romFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +160
>          System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(CompilerParameters     options, String[] fileNames) +23
>         System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() +884
>         System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +9549320
>          System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean     isPrecompiledApp) +9872176
>         System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +44
>         System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +269

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was     "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths     @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET     Files\root\d7e8c5c7\64d2ef8e\12ln453k.cmdline".]
  System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +62
  System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +427
  System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +31
  System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager,     IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory,     HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception     appDomainCreationException) +530

[HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was     "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths     @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET     Files\root\d7e8c5c7\64d2ef8e\12ln453k.cmdline".]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873784
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr,     HttpContext context) +254
```

My website is not working I am not able to understand what is problem 
I called to he is saying this is from my end ..code error 
can any one tell me about this error
this is coming online when I am typing www..com

Comment: What is the environment you are deploying this application into ? Windows server version, network configuration, active directory, etc ... Also, could you tell us under which user account is running the application pool of your application ?

Comment: .net 4.0,hosted in godaddy ...working fine in local

Comment: @KrantiSingh did you get the solution of this issue. I am also facing same issue with Godaddy windows shared hosting. My website was working last night but now it is down since morning.

Comment: have you had any luck here?

Comment: Just call to Godaddy customer care ....this error was from server( Godaddy )

Comment: some time if you are uploading file at server ...Godaddy server not able to manage some file so you will get this kind of problem ....just call godaddy customer care ...thanks

Answer (score 8):

Just remove the highlighted section:

[image]

Comment: Could you insert directly your picture instead of posting a link please ?

Comment: I've edited your answer to add the image directly. @LeFlou - I think you need 10 reputation to post inline images - this is probably to stop spammers and those wanting to post innappropriate images directly from doing so.

Answer (score 4):

Add this tag in `<system.web>`:

```
<trust level="Full"/>
```

Comment compiler tag:

```
<system.codedom>
    <!--<compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>-->
</system.codedom>
```